# How to add a layout to the bottom of listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-button

I'm trying to add two buttons to the bottom of the list view with:

```
footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.page_navigation, null, false); 
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

to this point i have no problem but when i trying to manipulate the visibility of elements of the `footerview` i'm getting a null pointer exception. according to answers in the other questions maybe using fragments is a better solution. any idea how to do that

```
nextPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
previousPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
mainNav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousNext);
```

above buttons are `footerView` elements and i'm trying to control the visibility of them and updating the `listView` items in response to click of this buttons (i mean is callback to this buttons available?)
thanks in advance and excuse me for poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
nextPage = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.next);
previousPage = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.prev);
mainNav = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.previousNext);
```